# Detect custom "cloudy" shape in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I need to detect if a given image contains a cloud-like object. If it is too hard, a solution that can find a triangle with a number inside also would work for me. For context, both would indicate that the image is an addendum to an architectural project plan. Here are two examples of input images I'd need to process.

[image: First addendum - processed successfully]
[image: Second addendum - unable to find target objects]

This is the python code I'm using. I was able to detect correctly the first case, with only two "clouds", but the other one and most of the ones I need to process are way more complex.

```
import cv2


def process():
    file_name = "Pkg A - A6.1 - Addendum #1 4-11-23.jpg"

    # Reading image
    img2 = cv2.imread(file_name, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Reading same image in another variable and
    # converting to gray scale.
    img = cv2.imread(file_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Converting image to a binary image
    # (black and white only image).
    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Detecting shapes in image by selecting region
    # with same colors or intensity.
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Searching through every region selected to
    # find the required polygon.
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

        # Shortlisting the regions based on there area.
        if area > 200:
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)

            if len(approx) > 31:
                cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)

    # Create new image with updated contours
    cv2.imwrite("{}_updated.jpg".format(file_name), img2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process()
```

These are the results I'm getting. Notice I was able to contour both clouds in the first picture, but not only failed to detect clouds on the second but also detected something entirely wrong. Remember that all cloud objects will have that triangle with a number inside, so if it's possible to detect those instead, that's also great.

[image: First case - success]
[image: Second case - fail]

**EDIT: adding one more example of failure to detect an easier cloud**
This image has a very clear cloud, but it has too many lines and texts inside it, so my algorithm once again failed.
[image: Clearer cloud - still failed to process]

Comment: your approach, counting the number of corners of a simplified contour, is reasonable. it may need some tweaking, extra filtering, to be robust against false positives like the ones you demonstrate. -- triangles are easy to find. those cloud things _may_ also be easy to find, ***IF*** the basic feature of that cloud does not vary in scale between clouds. you ought to provide pictures with sufficient (and stated/known) resolution. those screenshots give insufficient detail to reliably detect those features.

Comment: Did you try simple template matching on the triangle symbols?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the clouds vary tremendously. Notice the second picture, the one I wasn't able to detect, in the very middle there is a thin vertical cloud with only a small part larger than the rest.

Comment: @Markus I didn't but I'm not sure it would work because I need triangles with a number inside. I'm afraid with an image as zoomed out and low quality as the second one it would identify many other triangles as false positives.

Comment: Also please bear in mind that there will in many cases be intersection, i.e. lines, text or dots inside my target objects.

Comment: the more complex the problem, the fewer options you have. your best is to train AI.

Comment: What are your tolerances for false positives (i.e. highlighting something that isn't a cloud/triangle) and false negatives (i.e. missing a cloud/triangle)? If you can accept a decent number of false positives, you can probably run a template search for the triangles (which don't vary greatly).

Comment: @Mozglubov I have some tolerance on false negatives, but would rather have zero false positives. Accepting false positives on triangle detection is way too risky in my opinion, as this is a very common shape. If we can on the other hand be sure that there is a digit inside that triangle, then the false positives will become less and less likely.

Comment: why do this visually at all? do these CAD programs not have native formats you can analyze? do they not annotate the PDFs with metadata to easily find those shapes? I'm sure there is a way to NOT have to scrape this out of a screenshot of other "image" export.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm open for an AI training approach, but I wouldn't be able to do it myself. Let me know if you have some algorithm / code in mind :)

Comment: I fail to see why this can't be solved by using source data. it's CAD. the data exists. you just need to know where the data is, and kick people until they give you that data instead of screenshots.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't get why you're bringing up CAD. All I have is PDFs containing those images. I'm trying to tackle this problem by converting the images in the PDF to a JPG, but any other approach that someone feels would work, I'll take it.

Comment: In your case implementing a generator for random training data seems pretty straight forward. Draw images with random text and a lot of straight and curved lines and boxes and add some cloud-like shapes on it. This way you can get an arbitrary number of training images where you know the position of the cloud-like shapes.